# How to add another ordercomments field to woocommerce checkout

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Topic. I cant download an addon to woocommerce. Needed to edit the woocommerce code.

Pls help, it's very important.

Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

To add another order notes custom fields :

add in functions.php :

```
/**
 * add new order note field
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'customizing_checkout_fields', 10, 1 );
function customizing_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

    // Define new  custom Order Notes field data array
    $customer_note  = array(
        'type' => 'textarea',
        'class' => array('form-row-wide', 'notes'),
        'label' => __('Order Notes New', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder' => _x('Notes about your order, e.g. special notes for delivery.', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce')
    );

    $fields['order']['billing_new_customer_note'] = $customer_note;

    return $fields;
}

/**
 * Process the checkout
 */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'customise_checkout_field_process');
function customise_checkout_field_process()
{
  #if the field is set, if not then show an error message.
  if (!$_POST['billing_new_customer_note']) wc_add_notice(__('Please enter Order Notes New value.') , 'error');
}

/**
 * Update the order meta with field value
 */
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custome_checkout_field_update_order_meta');
function custome_checkout_field_update_order_meta($order_id)
{
  if (!empty($_POST['billing_new_customer_note'])) {
    update_post_meta($order_id, 'billing_new_customer_note', sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_new_customer_note']));
  }
}
```

**Display field value on the order edit page**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_edit', 10, 1 );
  function custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_edit($order){
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Order Notes New').':</strong> <br/>' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'billing_new_customer_note', true ) . '</p>';
    }
```

**Display field In Order review page after order note**

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table','custom_checkout_field_display_order_reviews',20);
    function custom_checkout_field_display_order_reviews( $order ){  
        ?>
        <table class="woocommerce-table shop_table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Custom order note </th>
                    <td><?php echo "<strong>".get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'billing_new_customer_note', true )."</strong>"; ?></td>
                </tr>
             </tbody>
        </table>
    <?php }
```

Comment: Thank you so much dear friend ! Also, i want it to get into the database too kike the first woocommerce comment note. How can i do this ?

Comment: It have already added a code to save new order note into database. you can find it in order edit dashboard in admin under original order note fields

Comment: I can't. Are you sure?.. if i can't see it in the order edit section what should i do.

Comment: here https://prnt.sc/o9uvsz you can see added New Order notes.

Comment: Maybe i didnt added the code to the right function.php file ? There is more than one function.php file. In which one should i add the code

Comment: in my answer, i have used **woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address** action to add into database. did you add this function in your functions.php file?

Comment: No. Can you send it to me here pls?

Comment: i have update my answer i have separate function from mixed code. you can find below **Display field value on the order edit page** line.

Comment: Thank you dear friend. But it also doing "please enter order notes new value" every time im hitiing confirm on checkout. Cant checkout. Also doesnt writing it in the database

Comment: there is a validation on that field if field empty you can not checkout. if you want to remove validation comment this line from code : **add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'customise_checkout_field_process');** it will entry in database after once order submit.

Comment: Where to put this codeline ?

Comment: i have already added this code line in my answer. from there you have to just comment this line or remove. so you will not asked to  **please enter order notes new value"** when hitting confirm on checkout.

Comment: Thank you very much. The new note is in the special fields section in the admin edit section. How can i get it up to the order derails ?

Comment: i have added a new code section **Display field In Order review page after order note** which is display custom order note in order review page in my answer. please see https://prnt.sc/oad6pi

Comment: Thank you my friend. Where should i put this code? Where? In which file?

Comment: along with all above code.

Comment: Thank you. I want to do it in a different way. I have a colum in my wp_posts table that called "sec_note". Can you write for me a function that will update it with the answer that putted in the textarea we made? Pls it will help me so much for my highschool final project